# My custom element is not working in Polymer shop app, but working in Polymer starter kit?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, polymer-starter-kit, custom-element

### **PROBLEM:**

I've created a custom "properties" grid system to use universally on any element. In every project thus far, I've had no problem using it...But when I try to use it in the [Polymer Shop App Demo](https://github.com/Polymer/shop), it doesn't work. Here's my custom property system that I'm importing in: https://github.com/oneezy/steel-properties

In Chrome dev tools network tab, it says that it's loading normally, however when I inspect an element it doesn't show up in the css and has no effect! It's got me scratching my head because it works completely fine w/ Polymer Starter Kit and in other projects...

I've included a short video showing my problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpyYxXTMdkU

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong???

### **UPDATE:**

By changing `shadow` to `shady` in the shop app's `index.html` file, everything seems to work as expected:

---

```
    Polymer = {lazyRegister: true, dom: 'shadow'};

            becomes...

    Polymer = {lazyRegister: true, dom: 'shady'};
```

But what are the ramifications of this?

---

[Steel-Properties](https://github.com/oneezy/steel-properties) is meant to be used as a "universal" way for initial layout so you can quickly use it on any element. When I include steel-properties into a file, it goes in and calls other files that have specific style properties written out, and you then can write these properties directly into your markup.

### **EXAMPLE:**

**HTML Markup:**
`<body mobile-bg="blue" tablet-bg="green" desktop-bg="yellow"></body>`

**Output:**
[image]

**The Code:**
[image]

As you can see, `steel-properties` is not your typical `<custom-element>`. It's really just importing in style sheets with `[attribute="property"]`'s.

### So my questions now are:

- Should I be doing it this way or am I going about it wrong?
- What would be the proper way to write my "steel-properties" so that it can work with both `shadow` and `shady` DOM universally?
- What are the ramifications of switching `shadow` to `shady` DOM in the shop app?
- What is the main reason for using `shadow` DOM instead of `shady` DOM in the shop app but not the Polymer Starter Kit? (performance?)

Comment: You should really use [shared-styles](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules) to create style sheets. External style sheets are deprecated in Polymer

Comment: I'm beginning to... easing into it

Comment: Shared-styles are not that different, you only need to create an html instead of css file(which you already have) and use your style tag inside polymer local dom structure. In order to use you have to add `include="<shared-style-id>"` in the element where you want to use it. Hopefully with these changes you should be able to see your `steel-properties` work with `Apptoolbox`